# Div just not playing ball and going where i want it

Tags: html, css, position

the div with the word test it in, just will not go up the top right..... despite me floating right and specifying top 0

http://www.e-fluential.com/offline/

HELP!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Care to paste the relevant code here? When you finally remove the `/offline/` from your website, this question will be useless, unless you also put the details on SO. Then the question and answer can live on for years to come, to help other hapless souls stuck fighting HTML and CSS.

Comment: Which browsers show the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give the element the following properties:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

This will make the element go to the top right corner. If you want the element to go to the top right corner of its parent you should give the parent the following property:

```
position: relative;
```

This will position the element `relative` to its parent.

Another solution would be to wrap the elements on the left with a wrapper, which you will then need to give a `width` and a `float: left;`, do the same with the elements that should go right but instead of floating it left give it a `float: right;`. The total width of both wrappers should not extend the width of the parent.

You'll probably want to go with the second solution because you don't need to give your elements absolute coordinates that way.

- [Positioning elements](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp)
- [Floating elements](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_float.asp)

Comment: no it needs to stay with the main div its in just to the right of the blah blah

Comment: @Lee: Where does it need to go? I'm confused.

Comment: @Lee: I've updated my answer. You should give the `mainbody` the property `position: relative;`.

Comment: @thirtydot: it needs to go floating right inline with Solutions Overview

Comment: Try `left: 700px` instead (in addition to @Kevin's tips, but remove the `right` rule). If this still isn't right, try taking a screenshot and marking where it should go.

Comment: @Kevin: they are in a wrapper with width and float left, the test div is float right and with width and top but it won't go ??

Comment: @Lee: The `frontwidth` elements should all go in 1 wrapper and the `textcarousel` should go into its own wrapper.

Comment: @Kevin I have done this now and its close but it looks like the divs aren't in the mainbody now even though they are ??

Comment: @Lee: You mean that the `mainbody` doesn't expand to contain the elements? This is true. To fix this you will have to give the `mainbody` the property `overflow: auto;`. This will make the `mainbody` expand to contain the floated elements.

Comment: @Kevin: Thats ace.... spot on... only thing is now in Dreamweaver its off center but i can work with that lol... Can i get your msn or something if i need more help ?

Comment: @Lee: You should just post another question on SO if you can't work out what the problem is. Don't forget to search before posting a question though :).